# WMIC is NOT on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wmic

I recently installed Windows XP on a computer because I wanted to confirm some stuff with WMIC. What I wanted to confirm is not relevant to my problem. WMIC is NOT THERE. On Windows 7 I can type "WMIC" from the command line and it runs just fine. On another iteration of XP I typed WMIC and it had to install it, fine. I can't use it there because what I'm testing requires a format.

I've updated EVERYTHING and installed all service packs (first two than the unofficial four) but it's still not there! I did a search for the file, and it didn't find it. I went to the folder in which the file is supposed to be, and it wasn't there (Windows\System32\wbem). What did I do wrong? How do I install WMIC onto Windows XP?

Comment: Which version of XP is it? Home versions don't have proper/full WMI support.

Comment: IT IS HOME EDITION. FORGET MY LIFE. Thanks -.-;

Comment: No problem., I threw it in an official answer, for completeness. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Home versions of XP don't have proper/full WMI support, so the odds are the `WMIC` utility just isn't included, regardless of the SP or updates applied.

If you *really* need it, perhaps try taking a copy from an XP Pro machine.

Comment: As an alternative, you can also install PowerShell and use [Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd315379.aspx)